# Variable names not showing in Stata after importing Excel file

Tags: stata

I am trying to import an Excel file which has the first row as the variable names.  Once imported the variable viewer shows only `a,b,c`.... for the variable names.    Is there a command to let Stata know that the first row is the variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type `db import excel` you will see a tick box `Import first row as variable names`.

Alternatively, use the `firstrow` option (not command) from the command line:

`import excel` ... `, firstrow`

For more, read the help:

`help import excel`